# Why is my subview not showing on top of the stack?

Tags: ios, objective-c, addsubview

I am trying to add a camera capture subview on top of my NavigationStack but even though the code runs fine according to debugs the subview is not shown on top so I cannot scan using the camera

The code looks as follows, why would it not show on top of the stack?

```
- (IBAction)transactionListViewCameraBtn_Pressed:(id)sender {

    if([NWTillHelper isDebug] == 1) {
        NSLog(@"%s entered", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    }

    NSLog(@"jongel1");
    self.capture.delegate = self;
    NSLog(@"jongel2");
    [self applyOrientation];
    NSLog(@"jongel3");
    self.capture = [[ZXCapture alloc] init];
    self.capture.camera = self.capture.back;
    self.capture.focusMode = AVCaptureFocusModeContinuousAutoFocus;
    NSLog(@"jongel4");
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:self.capture.layer];
    NSLog(@"jongel5");
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.scanRectView];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.decodedLabel];
    NSLog(@"jongel6");
}
```

Comment: How can you set `delegate` for `self.capture` before initializing `self.capture`? ;)

Comment: BLEH thats what I get for working through the night !!!!! going to bed now works like a charm when you do things in the right order

Comment: Can i add an answer for your question ? ;)

Comment: of course I will accept it right away

Comment: Congratulation and good night ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seem like you set `delegate` for `self.capture` before initializing `self.capture`. Try to set `delegate` after you initialize `self.capture`.

Comment: I think you mean AFTER though not before INIT

Comment: @MattDouhan My mistake, i have updated my answer. Thank you.